# Encoded message in Graylog

Tags: logging, wildfly, wildfly-10, graylog2, graylog

I have the following problem: I installes Graylog as described here:

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-graylog2-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

and then I configured GELF module for Wildfly 10:

http://logging.paluch.biz/examples/wildfly.html

here is my configuration:

```
<custom-handler name="GelfLogger" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.wildfly.WildFlyGelfLogHandler" module="biz.paluch.logging">
          <level name="DEBUG" />
          <properties>
            <property name="host" value="udp:localhost" />
            <property name="port" value="8514" />
            <property name="version" value="1.1" />
            <property name="facility" value="smarttherapy" />
            <property name="extractStackTrace" value="true" />
            <property name="filterStackTrace" value="false" />
            <property name="includeLogMessageParameters" value="true" />
            <property name="mdcProfiling" value="true" />
            <property name="timestampPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSS" />
            <property name="maximumMessageSize" value="8192" />
            <property name="additionalFields" value="fieldName1=fieldValue1,fieldName2=fieldValue2" />
            <property name="additionalFieldTypes" value="fieldName1=String,fieldName2=Double,fieldName3=Long" />
            <property name="mdcFields" value="mdcField1,mdcField2" />
            <property name="dynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields" />
            <property name="includeFullMdc" value="true" />
          </properties>
        </custom-handler>
```

however it doesn't work correctly:

1. facility is unknown in my input in graylog
2. messages are encoded somehow

facility
 
Unknown

full_message
 
��R�O�0�W�>ò�7QbbD

does any body knows what's wrong with this configuration? when I send UDP packet using console it appears just normally.

thanks for any help

Comment: the link says: _This tutorial is for an outdated version of Graylog2. A new version is available here: How To Install Graylog on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7._

Comment: Maybe but it should work with that version as well... I'll try to remove the existing and install Graylog again.

Comment: Why do you use port `8514`? This port suggests you're using the syslog input and not the GELF input (which defaults to port 12201).